# How do I Setup this mocked object in Xunit?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, xunit

So I have this class that accesses data in a database. Let's call it dbAccessor. I have an interface for it called IDbAccessor. I am writing xunit tests for a file that utilizes this IDbAccessor. Can someone explain how to set up this mocked object so that it returns an object?

Currently, my test file looks like this

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestDB_Accessor()
{
    var dbAccessorMock = CreateMock<IDbAccessor>();
    
    // This fails before it even reaches the verification. Because inside
    // of dbAccessor, there is a line of code that utilizes the return
    // data from the database, but in this case, it is null, I believe
    // because this dbAccessorMock has not been set up to return an obj. 
    await dbAccessorMock.PostItem(CreateMock<Dog>().Object);
    
    // Verification
    dbAccessorMock.Verify(x => x.PostItem(It.IsAny<Dog>()));
}
```

But the above test code does not work because I believe the dbAccessorMock variable has not been set up to return an object. It just returns null, thus the code/test will fail. Does anyone know the proper way to set up this mock object to ensure that it returns something?

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here? At the minute you're testing a mock rather than any actual code?

Comment: I am trying to test the PostItem method in my dbAccessor. But right now that dbAccessor is returning null instead of an object.

Comment: But you've mocked your db accessor? Surely you should be using the actual implementation?

Comment: Sorry new to xunit and C# here, so instead of using the CreateMock<IEntityAccessor>, you are saying I can just use the actual interface instead of a mock? Like var dbAccessor = new IDbAccessor()?

Comment: It's no issue, could you post the actual class/method you're testing and what you're trying to mock in that?

Comment: But yes, you want to test a function and mock out any dependencies, whether that be a database, another class etc